# Computer disappeared from Workgroup

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, local-area-network, workgroup

I've a LAN that has 8 computers running Windows XP and only one (Computer A) running Windows Server 2003.

When computer A boots, it shows up in all computers' Workgroups, but after 15-30 minutes, it disappears from the Workgroup in *all* computers, **including itself**. However, files can still be transferred from and to A via full path shortcuts and network drive maps still work.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem or not, but if that particular computer is turned on while the LAN cable is plugged in, it doesn't connect to the network, but it connects if the cable is plugged in after the computer is run.

Any tips why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Computer browsing/network neighborhood is fairly unreliable w/out [WINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service) and/or dynamic DNS. WINS is the easiest solution.
Give the Server 2003 computer a static IP.
Add the WINS service to the Server 2003 computer.
In the scope of the DHCP server (probably the router or the Server 2003 computer) add the IP of Server 2003 computer for the WINS server.
Do an IP config /release & /renew on each of the other 7 computers, or reboot them.
If the router is doing DHCP and doesn't have an option for WINS in the scope then disable DHCP on the router, install DHCP service on the Server 2003.
Configure the DHCP scope w/ options for router, DNS server(s), WINS (0xh for the type).